# Is the following morphism etale

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $Y$ be a reduced noetherian $1$-dimensional scheme such that the normalization morphism $f:X \longrightarrow Y$ is finite. Let $g:Y\longrightarrow Z$ be a finite flat morphism, where $Z$ is a connected (1-dimensional) Dedekind scheme.

Suppose that the morphism $g\circ f$ from $X$ to $Z$ is etale.

**Question.** Is the morphism $g:Y\longrightarrow Z$ etale?

**Remark.** The hypothesis on the dimension is not necessary probably.

**Remark.** One may assume $Y$ to be integral.

**Remark.** To assure that $f$ is finite one may suppose that $Y$ is excellent.

Interesting cases one may consider are $Z\subset \mathrm{Spec} \mathbf{Z}$ or $Z\subset \mathbf{P}^1_k$ non-empty open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is étale, then $Y$ is regular because $Z$ is regular. Thus $X=Y$. So the anwser to your question is yes if and only if  $X=Y$.

Comment: If $Y$ is not normal then can the _hypothesis_ of the question ever be true? i.e. does there ever exist $Z$ and some map $Y\to Z$ as in the question such that the induced map $X\to Z$ is etale with $X$ the normalization? 

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, start with an étale double cover $X\to Z$ with a fibre consisting of two points. Construct $Y$ as the nodal "curve" with these two points identified.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes: $Y=$ union of the two diagonals in the plane, $Z=$ the $x$-axis, map= the $x$-projection.

Comment: @Torsten: You beat me by 3 minutes on this one.

Comment: Very nice -- thanks to both of you.